# Almost a prime number recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions, conjectures

For the number of partitions of n into prime parts $a(n)$ it holds 
$$a(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n q(k)a(n-k)\tag 1$$
where $q(n)$ the sum of all different prime factors of $n$.
Due to https://oeis.org/A000607.

I have found that 
$$a(p_n)\approx a(p_{n-2})+a(p_{n-1})\tag 2$$ 
and conjecture the asymptotic relation.

> $$\log a(p_n)\sim \log \big(a(p_{n-2})+a(p_{n-1})\big )\tag 3$$

[image]

On x-axis the prime numbers $p_n$ are plotted. The blue lines correspond to $a(p_n)$ and the red lines correspond to $a(p_{n-2})+a(p_{n-1})$.

On the oeis site above there is also a formula
$$a(n)\sim e^{2\pi\sqrt{n/\log n}\,/\sqrt{3}}\tag 4$$
but I don't know if this really helps?

> Can this (reformulated) conjecture be proved?

Comment: Doesn't the PNT give $p_n/\log p_n\sim n$, so $a(p_n)\sim e^{2\pi\sqrt n/\sqrt 3}$? That would mean you'd have to prove something along the lines of $e^{2\pi\sqrt{n}/\sqrt 3}\sim e^{2\pi\sqrt{n-2}/\sqrt 3}+e^{2\pi\sqrt{n-1}/\sqrt 3}$. Maybe try to sum the Taylor series.

Comment: @Mastrem: I have reformulated the conjecture.

Comment: The asymptotic formula gives $\log a(p_n)\sim \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt n$.